# Using RSVP abbreviation as UI element

Tags: tables, text, readability

Our software deals with managing event attendance, so that manager can see how many people accepted/rejected/not responded to the invites.

So the question is the "RSVP" abbreviation popular enough, that (english speaking) people will understand what it means?

English is not my native language, so when I first saw this abbreviation it was very confusing to me, especially considering that it's abbreviated from French.

Answer (score 2):

Would depend on the sophistication of your audience. I'm a native speaker and I've always had trouble with that abbreviation. But if you have doubts about using it, I would consider using a term that had less potential for confusion.

You may also look at some of the popular event sites for some guidance here. But be careful, their use of the term doesn't guarantee that it isn't confusing. For example, Facebook,  probably the most widely used site for posting events doesn't use the term.

Comment: I'm a Native English Speaker in the UK.  And its been going out of fashion for a long time.  I'd stick to the simple word 'reply'.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker and although my English is quite okay, I didn't know the meaning of the abbreviation. Although the target group are native speakers, why make things complicated?

Comment: @PhillipW I see Facebook and Eventbrite offer the standard options the OP suggested directly.

Comment: Just for completeness:-  it stands for Répondez S'il Vous Plaît ("A response would be welcomed") - it used to be used on the card invitations to physical events such as weddings.

Answer (score 0):

In the Outlook app on Android the abbreviation RSVP is used as a clickable control to indicate attendance to an event. However that is the only occurrence I have seen.

Why not just use 'ATTEND' or 'ACCEPT'? They are widely used.